# Incompatibility between reledmac and floatrow

Tags: reledmac, floatrow

Working on my book, which has a critical edition, I needed to put two geometrical figures side by side (the figure from a source used by the author of the text I am editing, plus the figure as is in the manuscript). Having tried the minipage with pretty an awful result (the captions were vertically misaligned), I turned, then, to floatrow. The problem, so it seems, is that reledmac is incompatible with floatrow. If I comment floatrow everything returns to the normal. Any solution (safe minipage)?

Error message says: Command \Xhsize already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

````
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}
\lineation{page}
\fnpos{familiar-critical}
\Xlemmafont{\mdseries}
\usepackage[floatrowsep=qquad]{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{floatrow}
      \ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{\caption[Climas e proximidade dos polos (fig. de Pérez de Moya)]{Diminuição dos climas em função da proximidade dos polos (fig. de Pérez de Moya)}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.43]{moya_climas.png}}
      \ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{\caption[Climas e proximidade dos polos (fig. de Castel-Branco)]{Diminuição dos climas em função da proximidade dos polos (fig. de Castel-Branco)}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.47]{Figura_3.2-v2_b.png}}
     \end{floatrow}
  \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{floatrow}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption[Diminuição dos climas em função da proximidade dos polos (fig. de Pérez de Moya)]{Diminuição dos climas em função da proximidade dos polos (fig. de Pérez de Moya)}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.43]{moya_climas.png}}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption[Diminuição dos climas em função da proximidade dos polos (fig. de Pérez de Moya)]{Diminuição dos climas em função da proximidade dos polos (fig. de Castel-Branco)}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.47]{Figura_3.2-v2_b.png}}
    \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}


\end{document}```
````

Comment: maybe open a github issue, I could have time next week to look for this.

Comment: I know floatrow uses a picture environment and you cannot nest pictures.  No idea how reledmac works.  Personally, I avoid both packages and use paracol and subcaption instead.